# Max/Min methods returning nothing or incorrect number

Tags: c, methods, arguments

I need to put arguments into an array and get the max/min and average of the numbers using methods. It does not return the anticipated results. I'm at my wits end with this. If anyone could let me know what I'm doing wrong I'd be very thankful. Here's the mess I've made in my frustration.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getGrade(int argc, char *argv[]);
int findMaximum(int grade[]);
int findMinimum(int grade[]);
float calculateAverage(int grade[]);
void printResults(int maximum, int minimum, float average);

int argc;
int grade[50];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    getGrade(argc,argv);
    int max = findMaximum(grade);
    int min = findMinimum(grade);
    float avg = calculateAverage(grade);
    printResults(max,min,avg);
return 0;
}
void getGrade(int argc, char *argv[]){
    for(int i=1;i<=argc-1;i++)
        grade[i-1]=atoi(argv[i]);
}
int findMaximum(int grade[]){
    int max;
    int size = argc-1;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
       if(grade[i]>grade[0]){
            max = grade[i];}
       else{
            max = grade[0];}
    }
         return max;
}
int findMinimum(int grade[]){
    int min;
    int size= argc-1;
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        if(grade[i]<grade[0])
           min=grade[i];
    }
    return min;
}
float calculateAverage(int grade[]){
    float avg=0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<=argc; i++)
        avg= grade[i]+avg;
    return avg/(argc-1);
}
void printResults(int maximum, int minimum, float average){
    printf("Maximum Grade: %d\nMinimum Grade: %d\nAverage Grade: %.2f\n",maximum,minimum, average);
}
```

I'm new to C so please be kind and excuse the mess this has become.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your global variable argc is never assigned a value. In order to not change your code too much, just rename it Argc:

```
int Argc;
int grade[50];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Argc=argc;
    getGrade(argc,argv);
```

Then proceed as suggested by previous poster:

```
   int findMaximum(int grade[]){
    int max;
    int size = Argc-1;
    max=grade[0];
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
       if(grade[i]>max){
            max = grade[i];}
    }
         return max;
}

int findMinimum(int grade[]){
    int min=grade[0];
    int size= Argc-1;
    for(int i=1; i<size;i++){
        if(grade[i]<min)
           min=grade[i];
    }
    return min;
}
```

Ditto for calculateAverage.

```
./a.out 8 9 5 2
Maximum Grade: 9
Minimum Grade: 2
Average Grade: 6.00
```

Answer (score 2):

In your maximum and minimum functions you compare each element of the list with the first one of the list

```
if(grade[i]>grade[0])
```

Instead you should set max to grade[0] before the loop and instead compare to max. So your function would become:

```
int findMaximum(int grade[]){
  int max = grade[0];
  int size = argc-1;
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    if(grade[i]>max){
        max = grade[i];}
  }
return max;
}
```

Note that this function assumes that there is at least one element in the list. To avoid that, you can set max to `INT_MIN` instead, so that the first element will always be greater than the current `max`.

And you can do the same just switched around for the minimum function.